# US visiting UK re entry on tourist visa

Tags: usa, tourist-visas

I have a friend from USA who visited UK last year from June - Dec staying within her tourist visa for approx 5 1/2 months. How soon can she return to UK on a new tourist visa and can she stay up to another 6 months or is there a limit to how much time she can be here in a year period? And if so is that a year from her first entry here or from Jan 1st??

Comment: She actually got a visa, or is she entering visa-free as US passport holders are permitted to do?

Comment: @Roz There is no published timeframe. The UK Immigeation Rules state that the person seeking visa-free entry must be a genuine visitor and will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits. As a general indication, it would be advisable to spend at least as long outside the UK as within it, and to bring the same documents needed to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK Border. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.